# How google handle site traffic in google analytics

Tags: seo, google, google-analytics, web-traffic

I have a site with address www.exam.com and I have put Google analytics javascript scripts in it. I have made an app for my site, I want that everytime a user uses app, he visit the site in the application with built in browser which is inside the application ( I am using C# for application and .NET web browser ). User will address www.example.com/appvisit in the app and I just have put google analytics scripts in that page and nothing else.

And I want to disallow this address /appvisit in my robots.txt file . I want to know that Is there any problem with doing this? will google crawl in the /appvisit directory ? Does google hate this work? and will google think this traffic is true and normal?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no problem with disallowing that address in your robots.txt file. Google won't crawl it, but some crawlers ignore robots.txt. There is nothing wrong with saying that part of your site shouldn't be crawled. Measuring visitors is a different thing to letting search engines index your site.

(I did find someone who found that URLs used by analytics were then used for crawling, but as I say Google obeys robots.txt http://www.monkeylytics.com/googlebot-crawls-based-on-google-analytics-data/)

Comment: So visiting the example.com/appvisit is exactly like visiting example.com for google ?

Comment: No. If you block example.com/appvisit then they won't crawl it, though they will count visitors using analytics. They will crawl other pages on example.com, but won't count visitors.

Comment: I'm a little confused, So if 10 people visit example.com/appvisit and 2 people visit example.com/index.php and in both two pages there is google analytics javascript scripts, So Google will say my  website visitors are 12 or not ?

Comment: Google will say there are 12 in that case, but you said above that analytics are in /appvisit and nowhere else.